# Ubuntu 14.10 upgraded from 14.04 won't start

Tags: upgrade, updates

I received on my 14.04 version that I can upgrade IT to 14.10. I accepted everything. The updater did download & install files that it needed and asked me to restart the laptop to complete the update. After that, the system shutdown, Lenovo logo appeared on the screen and it got stuck after the logo with a blank black screen and an underline flickering to my left upper screen. What can I do to fix that?

PS: I have tried keeping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting to enter in recovery and repair packages, or enter in 'safe mode' even without networking but still no effect. I can't pass that blank screen.